# onitemdatabound doesn't work after postback

Tags: asp.net, repeater, selectedindexchanged, itemdatabound

Here is my page codes. I just want to display my records. There is also search panel at the page. In the search panel, there are a couple of dropdownlist control and they have OnSelectedIndexChanged methods. When I change the selected item on the first dropdownlist, my onItemDatabound events which belongs the repeater does not work any more.

What happens instead: in the `ItemDataBound` event, I add the each record's picture at the panels dynamically. So, when I change the selected item of the dropdownlist the pictures disappear.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindToPage();            
    }
}

protected void DataBindToPage()
{
    rptLast.DataSource = EntitiyProvider.GetAdvertListLatest();
    rptLast.DataBind();

    rptSchool.DataSource = EntitiyProvider.GetAdvertListLatest("Ders Kitabı");
    rptSchool.DataBind();

    rptBook.DataSource = EntitiyProvider.GetAdvertListLatest("Edebi Eser");
    rptBook.DataBind();
}

protected void rptLast_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Advert adv = (Advert)e.Item.DataItem;            
        Panel pnlLastAdvertPic = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlLastAdvertPic");
        List<AdvertPicture> advPic = EntitiyProvider.GetAdvertKapakPicByAdvertId(adv.id);
        if (advPic.Count != 0)
        {
            string picPath = string.Empty;
            foreach (AdvertPicture item in advPic)
            {
                if (item.primePicture == true)
                {
                    picPath = item.picturePath;
                }
            }
            if (picPath == string.Empty)
            {
                pnlLastAdvertPic.Controls.Add(new Image { ImageUrl = "~/uploads/" + advPic[0].picturePath, Width = 140, CssClass="rpTable" });
            }
            else
            {
                pnlLastAdvertPic.Controls.Add(new Image { ImageUrl = "~/uploads/" + picPath, Width = 140, CssClass = "rpTable" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pnlLastAdvertPic.Controls.Add(new Image { ImageUrl = "~/images/Noimage.gif", Width = 120, CssClass = "rpTable" });
        }

     }           

 }
```

Comment: in the ItemDataBound event, I add the each record's picture at the panels. So, when I change the selected item of dropdownlist the pictures disappear

Comment: the reason is that you are not creating these dynamical controls on postback. But you have to recreate them always. Instead i would use a nested repeater for the images.

Comment: thanks for your help, i realized that databinding is done only before postback so itemDataBound events are not fired any more. Thanks again.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should have @TimSchmelter post his comment as an answer so you can choose it. This will help any future users with a similar problem.